# Magic Square confusion

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    
    const int maxsize=21 ;
    int magq[maxsize][maxsize] ;  
    int size ;                    

    
    cout << "Magic Square" << endl ;
    cout << "Size (odd): " ;
    cin >> size ;
    if( size<=0 || size>maxsize)
    {
    cout << "Size to big" << endl ;
    exit(1) ;
    }
    if( 1!=size%2)
    {
    cout << "Not an odd nr. " << endl ;
    exit(1) ;
    }

    
    for( int x=0; x<size; x++)
    for( int y=0; y<size; y++)
        magq[x][y] = 0 ;

    // In the lecture it is said to put the nr. 1 in the first row middle column 
    int x=(size-1)/2 ;  
    int y=0 ;
    magq[x][y]=1 ; //As we can clearly see here magq[x][y] for i.e size=5 is magq[2][0]
                      // which is not first row middle column
    for( int z=2; z<=size*size; z++)
    {
    
    int xneu=(x+1)%size ; // oder: x<size-1 ? x+1 : 0  
    int yneu=y>0 ? y-1 : size-1 ;
    if (0!=magq[xneu][yneu])
    {
        
        xneu=x ;
        yneu=y+1 ;
        if (yneu==size) 
        { 
        cout << "Boundary met under?!" << endl ;
        yneu=0 ;
        }
    }
    x=xneu ;
    y=yneu ;
    if( 0!=magq[x][y]) 
    {
        cout << "............some meaningless text!" << endl ;
        cout << "Nr.: " << z << "  Field: " << x << ", " << y << endl ;
        exit(1) ;
    }
    // cout << "Feld " << x << " " << y << "  Zahl " << z << endl ;
    magq[x][y]=z ;
    }

    
    for( int y=0; y<size; y++)
    {
    for( int x=0; x<size; x++)
        cout << setw(5) << magq[x][y] ;
    cout << endl ;
    }

 
    int diag1=0, diag2=0 ;  
    for( int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
    diag1 += magq[i][i] ;
    diag2 += magq[i][size-1-i] ;
    }
    cout << "Sum: (diag1, diag2, erwartet) "
     << diag1 << " " << diag2 << " " << (size*(size*size+1))/2 << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how is he moving in the matrix, in this exercise?
If we follow his initial notation then for n=5 (for example)

for z=2, xneu=3 and yneu=4, that is totally the reverse of the position 4,3 in which the number 2 should be stored. (Assuming that the index for rows and Column starts from 0 and ends at 4).

Can anyone explain to me, how are we moving in this program?

Comment: Get started without us and step through the program with the debugger that came with your development environment so you can see exactly what the program does as it does it.

Comment: Hint 1: Draw the board after every move.

Comment: x -> column_index
y -> row_index
so yes, magq[2][0] (x=2, y=0) is the middle column and first row

Comment: I did and that is why I did the thread. Cuz they don't align together. In the exercise it is said to put nr.1 in first row mid. column, So for n=5, you put nr. 1 in positon 0,2. There in the example that i posted, its 2,0. totally the reverse.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper when I fill a matrix with some values, I have the first index as the one that denotes the row and the 2nd as the one for the column so, for (int i....){for(int j,...){ cin >> matrix[i][j];}}

Comment: @imbAF you should take a look at the printing for loop, it prints a end-line after looping x values, so x is the column and y are rows. if you revert the two for loop with x and y you could read the square how you are guessing it, with y that are columns

Comment: I am confused. I understand that at some point he moves along a colloquium, but initially that is a row/column notation. At least this is how I know it. I always use the first index for rows and the 2nd one for column.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper When i do the following code :  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            cout <<setw(5)<< magq[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }                                                                                                                                          I get what it is expected, and that is the nr.1 on row 2, column 0

Comment: if it may help take a look to this pastebin https://pastebin.com/09j6bDcd
what really gives an order to columns and rows are the two for loop that prints the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program is about creating a magic square according to the "de la Loubère" method. There is a very good explanation on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Special_methods_of_construction). Or, because I saw some German text [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magisches_Quadrat#Konstruktion_magischer_Quadrate).

The mechanism is totally simple. Always Go up and right (take boundaries into account). If t´his place is already filled, then go one down.

The links show a step by step example.

Your confusion about the "Middle" comes from the fact that you assume array index 2 to be not the middle. But it is. Array indicess in C++ start wirth 0. So, if you have an odd number and make a integer division by 2, you will always get an even number, because the 0.5 part is truncated.

3/2=1, 5/2=2,  7/2=3 and so on. And with the example of 5, we will receive a 2 which is the middle of indeces 0,1,**2**,3,4.

This should answer your question.

Additionally, I will show you a different solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>

// The maximumn dimension of the magic square
constexpr size_t MaxDimension{ 21u };

// Some abbreviations for less typing work. Square will be implemented as a 2 dimensional std::array
using Square = std::array< std::array <int, MaxDimension>, MaxDimension>;

// Create a magic square following the method of "De-la-Loubère"
void createMagicSquare(Square& square, int sizeOfSquare) {
    
    // Reset all values in the square to 0
    square = {};

    // Starting row and column. Set to upper middle cell
    int row{}; int column{ sizeOfSquare / 2};

    // This will wrap a position if it leaves the boundary of the square
    auto wrap = [&sizeOfSquare](const int position) { return (position + sizeOfSquare) % sizeOfSquare; };

    // Now build the magic square and fill it with all numbers
    for (int runningNumber{ 1 }; runningNumber <= (sizeOfSquare * sizeOfSquare); ++runningNumber) {

        // Write number into cell at current position
        square[row][column] = runningNumber;

        // If the upper right cell is occupied
        if (square[wrap(row-1)][wrap(column+1)] != 0) {

            // Then just go one rowe down
            row = wrap(row + 1);
        } 
        else {
            // Next position will be upper right
            row = wrap(row - 1);
            column = wrap(column + 1);
        }
    }
}
// Output of the magic square
void display(Square& square, int sizeOfSquare)
{
    constexpr int Width = 4;
    std::cout << "\nThe Magic square is: \n\n";

    for (int row = 0; row < sizeOfSquare; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < sizeOfSquare; ++column)
            std::cout << std::setw(Width) << square[row][column];
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Give instruction what to do
    std::cout << "Enter The Size of the Magic Square (odd number (<=21): ";

    // Read user inpuit and make sure that it is a correct value
    if (int sizeOfSquare{}; (std::cin >> sizeOfSquare) and (sizeOfSquare <= MaxDimension) and (sizeOfSquare%2)) {

        // Define the empty square
        Square square{};

        // Fill it with magic numbers
        createMagicSquare(square, sizeOfSquare);

        // Show result
        display(square, sizeOfSquare);
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong Input\n";
}
```

Comment: "\n\n" isn't really cross platform, you should use std::endl instead.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Definitely not. Not for std::cout.

Comment: to my surprise you are right. I still prefer to use `std::endl` for readability but you are right the only difference for `std::cout` is the flush called by `std::endl`.